# Collections sort custom comparator

Tags: sorting, collections, comparator

I  have two classes :

```
public class Invoice {

private int InvoiceId;
private Customer customer;
private Date invoiceDate;
```

}

And

```
 public class Customer {
   private int customerId;
   private String customerType;
}
```

customerType field can have three values : F,H,B

I have an arrayList of Invoice objects, i want to sort it using the customerType property in a specific order :all the the invoice with customerType "F" then those with "H" then "B".

I tried to implement the Comparator interface , but the problem is that his method compare  takes two arguments of Customer  objects and the sorting is made in ascending or descending way.
This is the code :

```
  Collections sort(invoicesList, new Comparator<Invoice >() {
                 public int compare(Invoice  s1,Invoice s2) {
                        return s1.getCustomer().getCustomerTpe().equalsIgnoreCase("F").compareTo(s2.getCustomer().getCustomerTpe().equalsIgnoreCase("H"))

                      }
                  }
    );
```

Is there a way to sort my collection with  a specific order  with  three fileds value ?
Thnks

Answer (score 3):

One way to customize the sort order is to first map the arguments and then sort on the mapped values. In your case mapping of the `customerType` can be done by finding its index in the string "FHB". In Java 8, this might be expressed as

```
Collections.sort(invoicesList, Comparator.comparingInt(
    (invoice) -> "FHB".indexOf( invoice.getCustomer().getCustomerType() )));
```

Comment: I'm using java 6, i'll try to implement this with my version of java. thanks